# One-liner for partial string match in list lookup

Tags: python

Is there a simpler way to do the following?

```
filename = 'vudu_hail_20140101.xml'
acceptable_stems = ['vudu', 'google']

process_file = False
for acceptable_stem in acceptable_stems:
    if acceptable_stem in filename:
        process_file = True
```

Basically, I'm looking for a Boolean determinant on whether one of the stems is in the filename. How would this be done with a one-liner?

Comment: Shouldn't this go on to code review and not stay here on SO?

Comment: @Zizouz212 the code is here only as an explanation of the question; it is not a question for a code review.

Comment: @AmiTavory *Is there a simpler way to do the following?* It apparently works...

Comment: @Zizouz212 I see your point, but I think we're reading the emphasis differently. Guess we'll agree to disagree on this one.

Comment: Ahhh it's all good. I wouldn't worry too much about it. If other people step on to this, they can decide. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) keyword:

```
any([acceptable_stem in filename for acceptable_stem in acceptable_stems])
```

Examples:

```
>> filename = 'vudu_hail_20140101.xml'
>> acceptable_stems = ['vudu', 'google']
>> any([acceptable_stem in filename for acceptable_stem in acceptable_stems])
True

>> filename = 'vudu_hail_20140101.xml'
>> acceptable_stems = ['vuduf', 'google']
>> any([acceptable_stem in filename for acceptable_stem in acceptable_stems])
False
```

Comment: You can remove the square brackets if you want - no need to turn the generator into a `list`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - removing the brackets produced for me ``<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f97bff85410>``, not a boolean.

Comment: Resulted in `True` for me (using the first example) with `any(acceptable_stem in filename for acceptable_stem in acceptable_stems)`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I believe you, but it really doesn't by me. I'm running antiquated versions of IPython and python2.7 on CentOs6.5 (in a cave). Could that explain the difference?

Comment: @AmiTavory - when you put that expression *inside* the `any()`, it evaluates the generator expression (genexpr) and returns a boolean.

Comment: @dwanderson I cannot tell you how much I agree with your logic, and yet I'm alt-tabbing and seeing this on my IPython Notebook. And just to clarify, it is *in* the ``any``.

Comment: @AmiTavory I find that incredibly hard to imagine.

Comment: Did you re-run it? IPynbs tend to keep state even if previous things are changed; restart the interpreter/kernel/whatever-its-called and run it again.

Comment: Oh right I originally came here to mention that if the question is about *stems*, then the asker might prefer using `filename.startswith(acceptable_stem)`, in case `'vudu'` or `'google'` appears somewhere outside of the "stem".

Comment: Funny, I consistently get it in the IPython Notebook, but not in the console. I think I'll ask a question about it.